# Bayesian change detection (sampling the posterior of a Poisson distribution)

Tags: bayesian, poisson-distribution, change-point

I'm trying to work out how the posterior of a Poisson distribution is derived to enable me to detect changepoints. I'm trying to follow the example [here](https://medium.com/@anggerpamungkas/change-point-detection-1b2e588fe6b0).

$Y_i$ (events per year) is modelled using two Poisson distributions (one before, one after the changepoint), with lambda given for these distributions by gamma distributions. For one changepoint the posterior of $T$ (year of changepoint) is given as:

$$
\propto{((T\ -\ 1)\ +\ 1)}^{-2-\sum_{i\ =\ 1}^{T\ -\ 1}y_i}\ \Gamma(2\ +\ \sum_{i\ =\ 1}^{T\ -\ 1}y_i)\ \\ +\ {((112\ -\ (T\ -\ 1))\ +\ 1)}^{-2-\sum_{i\ =\ T}^{112}y_i}\ \Gamma(2\ +\ \sum_{i\ =\ T}^{112}y_i)
$$

How is this formula derived?

Comment: Welcome to CV! This site supports [LaTeX](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Mathematical_expressions). Please edit the question to include a LaTeX form of the equation, as the snapshot is completely unreadable and makes it difficult for answerers to help.

Comment: updated to include formulae